# How to get members of a named group with their manager?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, servicenow

I'm trying to pull data from Entra ID, namely the members of a group by name and the group members' manager info but I'm falling short one way or the other.

If I know the group's ID I can fetch the data with `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/members/microsoft.graph.user/?$select=<whatever attributes I want from the member>&$expand=manager($levels=max;$select=<whatever attributes I want from the manager>)`

This will only return members that are of type microsoft.graph.user (ie. omitting group members that are any other odata type and don't have the manager attribute, leading to an error response). The response looks good:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(<memberAttrs>,manager(<managerAttrs>))",
    "value": [
        {
            "accountEnabled": true,
            "businessPhones": [],
            "city": null,
            "companyName": null,
            "country": null,
            "department": null,
            "displayName": "Test member",
            "employeeId": null,
            "givenName": null,
            "id": <redacted>,
            "jobTitle": null,
            "mail": <redacted>,
            "mobilePhone": <redacted>,
            "officeLocation": null,
            "postalCode": null,
            "preferredLanguage": null,
            "state": null,
            "streetAddress": null,
            "surname": null,
            "userPrincipalName": <redacted>,
            "userType": "Member",
            "manager": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
                "id": <redacted>,
                "displayName": "Test manager",
                "userPrincipalName": <redacted>,
                "mail": <redacted>
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

With this approach the issue is the group ID, I really don't want to hard code it as I need to pull the data from multiple tenants with separate OAuth client credentials. Instead, I'm trying to get the group by its name and I can do it with this: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=displayName+eq+%27Test group%27&$expand=members`

This will return the group by name and its members expanded, but no matter what I try I can't seem to get the manager information with this approach. I even tried mimicking the expanded attribute conf from the first query `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=displayName+eq+%27Test group%27&$expand=members($levels=max;$select=<memberAttrs>,manager)` but no luck, I get lots of member attributes expanded that I really don't care about but manager is not on the returned list.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups(members(<memberAttrs>))",
    "value": [
        {
            ... <lots of group details> ...
            "members": [
                {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
                    "id": <redacted>,
                    "deletedDateTime": null,
                    "accountEnabled": true,
                    "ageGroup": null,
                    "businessPhones": [],
                    "city": null,
                    "companyName": null,
                    "consentProvidedForMinor": null,
                    "country": null,
                    "createdDateTime": "2023-05-24T12:28:22Z",
                    "creationType": null,
                    "department": null,
                    "displayName": "Test member",
                    "employeeId": null,
                    "employeeHireDate": null,
                    "employeeLeaveDateTime": null,
                    "employeeType": null,
                    "externalUserState": null,
                    "externalUserStateChangeDateTime": null,
                    "faxNumber": null,
                    "givenName": null,
                    "isLicenseReconciliationNeeded": false,
                    "jobTitle": null,
                    "legalAgeGroupClassification": null,
                    "mail": <redacted>,
                    "mailNickname": <redacted>,
                    "mobilePhone": <redacted>,
                    "onPremisesDistinguishedName": null,
                    "onPremisesDomainName": null,
                    "onPremisesImmutableId": null,
                    "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
                    "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
                    "onPremisesSamAccountName": null,
                    "onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
                    "onPremisesUserPrincipalName": null,
                    "otherMails": [],
                    "passwordPolicies": null,
                    "officeLocation": null,
                    "postalCode": null,
                    "preferredDataLocation": null,
                    "preferredLanguage": null,
                    "proxyAddresses": [
                        "SMTP:<redacted>"
                    ],
                    "refreshTokensValidFromDateTime": "2023-05-24T12:43:15Z",
                    "imAddresses": [],
                    "isResourceAccount": null,
                    "showInAddressList": null,
                    "securityIdentifier": <redacted>,
                    "signInSessionsValidFromDateTime": "2023-05-24T12:43:15Z",
                    "state": null,
                    "streetAddress": null,
                    "surname": null,
                    "usageLocation": null,
                    "userPrincipalName": <redacted>,
                    "userType": "Member",
                    "employeeOrgData": null,
                    "passwordProfile": null,
                    "assignedLicenses": [],
                    "assignedPlans": [],
                    "authorizationInfo": {
                        "certificateUserIds": []
                    },
                    "identities": [
                        {
                            "signInType": "userPrincipalName",
                            "issuer": <redacted>,
                            "issuerAssignedId": <redacted>
                        }
                    ],
                    "onPremisesProvisioningErrors": [],
                    "onPremisesExtensionAttributes": {
                        "extensionAttribute1": null,
                        "extensionAttribute2": null,
                        "extensionAttribute3": null,
                        "extensionAttribute4": null,
                        "extensionAttribute5": null,
                        "extensionAttribute6": null,
                        "extensionAttribute7": null,
                        "extensionAttribute8": null,
                        "extensionAttribute9": null,
                        "extensionAttribute10": null,
                        "extensionAttribute11": null,
                        "extensionAttribute12": null,
                        "extensionAttribute13": null,
                        "extensionAttribute14": null,
                        "extensionAttribute15": null
                    },
                    "provisionedPlans": [],
                    "serviceProvisioningErrors": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Am I fighting a lost battle, is there a better way of fetching the group members without knowing the group ID, or am I just forced to configure the group ID to the tenant specific configuration on the receiving side?

In case it makes a difference, I'm pulling the data into a domain separated ServiceNow instance and the Entra ID tenants are the customers of a MSP so the OOB way provided by Microsoft where you give total control of user import to the customers is not an option, the control must remain on the MSP side. It still leaves it to the customers to control who are members of that specific group and get imported into ServiceNow but there is no chance of inadvertent license cost hikes. Buiding some logic on the Azure side to push the data into ServiceNow is not an option, this is supposed to be a quick'n'dirty workaround to get the users into ServiceNow ASAP and without involving other teams or the customer.